# Hadoop fs -du-h sorting by size for M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

I am running this command --

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -du -h /user | sort -nr
```

and the output is not sorted in terms of gigs, Terabytes,gb

I found this command -

```
hdfs dfs -du -s /foo/bar/*tobedeleted | sort -r -k 1 -g | awk '{ suffix="KMGT"; for(i=0; $1>1024 && i < length(suffix); i++) $1/=1024; print int($1) substr(suffix, i, 1), $3; }'
```

but did not seem to work.

is there a way or a command line flag i can use to make it sort and output should look like--

```
123T  /xyz
124T  /xyd
126T  /vat
127G  /ayf
123G  /atd
```

Please help

regards
Mayur

Answer (score 14):

`hdfs dfs -du -h <PATH> | sed 's/ //' | sort -hr`

`sed` will strip out the space between the number and the unit, after which `sort` will be able to understand it.

Comment: It works as expected rather because when just use "sort -hr" the order is not ordered by unit instead of the file size in human readable i.e. 45 MB, 50 GB, 75 MB, 80 GB. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
hdfs dfs -du -h <PATH> | awk '{print $1$2,$3}' | sort -hr
```

Short explanation:

- The `hdfs` command gets the input data.
- The `awk` only prints the first three fields with a comma in between the 2nd and 3rd.
- The `-h` of `sort` compares human readable numbers like `2K` or `4G`, while the `-r` reverses the sort order.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Could you be so kind and elaborate on what is happening, and relate to the question a bit rather than a pure-code-snippet answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather old question, but stumbled across it while trying to do the same thing.  As you were providing the -h (human readable flag) it was converting the sizes to different units to make it easier for a human to read.  By leaving that flag off we get the aggregate summary of file lengths (in bytes).

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -du -s '/*' | sort -nr
```

Not as easy to read but means you can sort it correctly.

See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some small skript. It's primitive but reliable

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH_TO_FOLDER="$1"
hdfs dfs -du -h $PATH_TO_FOLDER > /tmp/output
cat /tmp/output | awk '$2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/  {print $1,$NF}' | sort -k1,1n
cat /tmp/output | awk ' {if ($2 == "K" ) print $1,$2,$NF}' | sort -k1,1n
cat /tmp/output | awk ' {if ($2 == "M" ) print $1,$2,$NF}' | sort -k1,1n
cat /tmp/output | awk ' {if ($2 == "G" ) print $1,$2,$NF}' | sort -k1,1n
cat /tmp/output | awk ' {if ($2 == "T" ) print $1,$2,$NF}' | sort -k1,1n
rm /tmp/output
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to sort `hdfs dfs -ls -h /path sort -r -n -k 5`

`-rw-r--r--   3 admin admin    108.5 M 2016-05-05 17:23 /user/admin/2008.csv.bz2
-rw-r--r--   3 admin admin      3.1 M 2016-05-17 16:19 /user/admin/warand_peace.txt
Found 11 items
drwxr-xr-x   - admin admin          0 2016-05-16 17:34 /user/admin/oozie-oozi
drwxr-xr-x   - admin admin          0 2016-05-16 16:35 /user/admin/Jars
drwxr-xr-x   - admin admin          0 2016-05-12 05:30 /user/admin/.Trash
drwxrwxrwx   - admin admin          0 2016-05-16 11:21 /user/admin/2015_11_21
drwxrwxrwx   - admin admin          0 2016-05-16 11:21 /user/admin/2015_11_20
drwxrwxrwx   - admin admin          0 2016-05-16 11:21 /user/admin/2015_11_19
drwxrwxrwx   - admin admin          0 2016-05-16 11:21 /user/admin/2015_11_18
drwx------   - admin admin          0 2016-05-16 17:38 /user/admin/.staging`

Comment: It did not work :(  ,  I am trying to get the disk usage. But i fixed it --  sort -r -k 1 -g | awk '{ suffix="KMGT"; for(i=0; $1>1024 && i < length(suffix); i++) $1/=1024; print int($1) substr(suffix, i, 1), $3; }' )